# Status bar overlaps Capacitor v2

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have a problem with the overlapping status bar. I want to have some margin or a safe area, that has other applications. I use `Capacitor v2` because in the project I have `Angular v7`. I would like to cut off the `status bar` from the application window. This problem is only for `iOS` devices.

I would like to cut off the `status bar` from the application window.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `capacitor.config.json`:

```json
{
  "ios": {
    // Configure the WebView's UIScrollView's content inset behavior
    // Default is never
    // Possible values are "automatic", "scrollableAxes", "never" and "always"
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/contentinsetadjustmentbehavior
    "contentInset": "always",
  },
}
```

Comment: This works for initial statusbar load.
However, when scrolling down, the statusbar disappears.
Any solution for that?